# Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "clk_1hz"

Tags: vhdl, fpga

!!EDIT!!

Ok, so after going through a few tutorials, I am now trying to create a similar process, in that I press a button to change the frequency with which a LED flashes, but this time using a multiplexer. The issue now is the error in the heading, Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "clk_1hz". Now i have read all of the different posts here but I can't seem to recognise what I'm doing wrong... I understand that it's telling me that i am assigning multiple different sources to "clk_1hz" and "clk_4hz", but it's telling me that this is happening within the port mapping of the code. I was under the impression that port mapping is equivalent to "soldering" the inputs and outputs of different components?

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    entity blinking_led is
        port(
            clk_50mhz : in std_logic ;
            btn_one : in std_logic;
            green_led : out std_logic
        );
    end entity;

    architecture behave of blinking_led is

        component MUXii
        port(
                a       : in std_logic;
                b       : in std_logic;
                sel     : in std_logic;
                z       : out std_logic
            );
        end component;

        component PLLii
        port(
                clk : in std_logic;
                y : out std_logic;
                x : out std_logic
            );
        end component;

    signal clk_1hz : std_logic ;
    signal clk_4hz : std_logic ;
    signal scaler : integer range 0 to 25000000 ;
    signal scaler_2 : integer range 0 to 12500000 ;
    signal LED  : std_logic ;
    signal a, b, z, sel, y, x : std_logic;

    begin

        Multiplexer_process : process( a, b, sel, z)
        begin
            if(sel = '1') then 
                z <= a;
            else
                z <= b;
            end if;
        end process Multiplexer_process;

    PLL_1_4_Hz : PLLii port map (
                clk     => clk_50mhz,
                y   => clk_1hz,
                x   => clk_4hz
            );

    MUX1 : MUXii port map (
                a   => clk_1hz,
                b   => clk_4hz,
                sel => btn_one,
                z   => LED
            );

    green_led <= LED;

        clk_1_4_hz_process : process( clk_50mhz )
        begin
            if(rising_edge(clk_50mhz)) then 
                if (scaler < 25000000) then 
                    scaler <= scaler + 1 ;
                    clk_1hz <= '0';
                else
                    scaler <= 0;
                    clk_1hz <= '1';
                end if;
                if (scaler_2 < 12500000) then 
                    scaler_2 <= scaler_2 + 1 ;
                    clk_4hz <= '0';
                else
                    scaler_2 <= 0;
                    clk_4hz <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;
        end process clk_1_4_hz_process;

    end behave;
```

Edit!!

So I managed to get rid of some of the issues i was having, and so the code is now...

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    entity PLL is port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        y : out std_logic;
        x : out std_logic
    );
    end PLL;

    architecture behaviour of PLL is 

    signal scaler : integer range 0 to 25000000 ;
    signal scaler_2 : integer range 0 to 12500000 ;
    signal clk_1hz : std_logic ;
    signal clk_4hz : std_logic ;

    begin
    clk_1_4_hz_process : process( clk )
    begin 
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then 
            if (scaler < 25000000) then 
                scaler <= scaler + 1 ;
                clk_1hz <= '0';
                x <= clk_1hz;
            else
                scaler <= 0;
                clk_1hz <= '1';
                x <= clk_1hz;
            end if;
        if (scaler_2 < 12500000) then 
            scaler_2 <= scaler_2 + 1 ;
            clk_4hz <= '0';
            y <= clk_4hz;
        else
            scaler_2 <= 0;
            clk_4hz <= '1';
            y <= clk_4hz;
        end if;
    end if;
    end process;

    end behaviour;


    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    entity MUX2to1 is port(
        A       : in std_logic;
        B       : in std_logic;
        Sel     : in std_logic;
        Z       : out std_logic
        );
    end MUX2to1;

    architecture behavior of MUX2to1 is
    begin
        MUX2to1_p : process (Sel, A, B) 
        begin
            if (Sel = '1') then
                Z <= A;
            else 
                Z <= B;
            end if; -- note that *end if* is two words
        end process;
    end behavior;

    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

    entity Com_Connect is port(
            clk_50mhz : in std_logic;
            btn_one : in std_logic;
            green_led : out std_logic
            );
    end Com_Connect;

    Architecture behaviour of Com_Connect is

    component PLL
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        y : out std_logic;
        x : out std_logic
    );
    end component PLL;

    component MUX2to1
    port(
        A       : in std_logic;
        B       : in std_logic;
        Sel     : in std_logic;
        Z       : out std_logic
    );
    end component MUX2to1;

    signal wire_one, wire_two : std_logic; 

    begin

    PLL1 :PLL port map (
    clk => Clk_50mhz, 
    y => wire_one, 
    x => wire_two
    );

    MUX2to1_1 : MUX2to1 port map (
    A => wire_two,
    B => wire_one, 
    Sel => btn_one,
    Z => green_led
    );

    end;
```

Although this comes up with no errors, it does not work (nothing happens, no LEDs light up, simulations are blank etc.) and it does have several warnings such as

Warning (15714): Some pins have incomplete I/O assignments. Refer to the I/O Assignment Warnings report for details

Critical Warning (332148): Timing requirements not met

The first I don't understand, as it's referring to the LED which i know i have mapped in the pin assignment module.
The second is a bit of a mystery to me, still trying to figure it out. Does anybody have any website recommendations or books that would help me grasp these basics better?

Cheers guys!

Comment: There is *no way* that any of this code could ever work. Surely Altera have got proper tutorials you could start from?

Comment: You know you are making a HW implementation of your code and this is not C?! One thing that helps you understand how this works is to look into the schematic implementation of your code to see how it is interpreted by the synthesis tool. You will be surprised if you look at this code's schematic after synthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit has completely changed the question. Please don't do that in the future.
You seem to have the general idea correct now, but there are still a few problems.

First of all, you don't show the implementations of your mux and pll components, although I can guess what they do based on their names. The reason that you are seeing multiple drivers is because your components are doing the same thing as your processes, and both the components and the processes are trying to drive the slow clocks and LED outputs. Remove your components; the processes alone will suffice.

The signal names used within your multiplexer process don't match the signal names used elsewhere.

Your "1Hz" clock will run at 2Hz. 
The duty cycle of your slow clocks will be 1:12-25 million because you only have the slow clocks go high for a single 50MHz cycle out of the whole slow period. You want a duty cycle of 1:1 or 50%. You can achive that by toggling the slow clocks when your counters expire instead. Note that this will also halve the frequency, so your 1Hz clock will actually be 1Hz, but the 4Hz will go to 2Hz.

If you change to toggling and want it to work in simulation, you will need to either set a default value, or define reset behaviour and reset in simulation. You should be simulating everything you write!

EDIT: Following up on your update:

- you have properly gone to a component only model (although the extra
  boilerplate for a mux that could be a 1-liner isn't my preferred
  style), but your big problem is still that the duty cycle is really,
  really low. So low that your LED won't flash on long enough for the
  human eye to see it.
- The incorrect frequency issue is still present.
- The I/O warning isn't caused by your VHDL directly, as pin assignment
  isn't handled there.
- Because this is a simple design that is slow, you don't really need
  to worry too much about timing. You probably haven't given it any
  timing constraints, which is why it says it didn't meet timing. If
  you ever go on to do more complex digital logic or working with
  higher frequencies (100+ MHz), properly constraining and meeting
  timing becomes important.

I also have a couple nitpicks that arent really errors:

- your component named `PLL` isn't a PLL, it is just a clock divider.
  More precisely, it is a counter. Most FPGAs, in addition to actual
  phase locked loops, have clock dividers that work similarly to
  in-fabric counters, but are hardened to operate faster and connect to
  the dedicated clock routes that are necessary with high speed clocks.
- Your `Com_Connect` architecture is
  written structurally, not behaviourally, although you named it
  `behaviour`.

Comment: Thanks a million, I solved the main issue, but opened up many new ones xP Updated the post this time!

Comment: Thank you my friend, that solved the problem entirely! The school boy errors and just not knowing how to structure VHDL properly has made this far more tedious than necessary... Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

The first statement within each `process` should be `if rising_edge (clk)`, so that everything within that process is treated as a register. Without this, you are telling the FPGA software to treat the contents as combinatorial logic or latches.

Here's an overview of the rules used by the FPGA software to decide if it is generating a register, a latch, or combinatorial logic:

- Register: every assignment within the process is triggered only on a clock edge (e.g. `if rising_edge (clk)`).
- Combinatorial logic: the process always assigns to all of its outputs. Inputs do not include any clock signals.
- Latch: anything else, e.g. one signal is not always assigned.

Generally you should avoid code that will produce a latch. They do not work very well (if at all). Your `LED` output is generated by a latch because it's not always assigned.

Comment: Very helpful! We made some progress last night in a similar direction with the rising clock edge (post was written last night, failed to send...). Anyway thanks a million for your help! Working through the tutorials as suggested above.